# How to add ColSideColors on heatmap.2 after performing bi-clustering (row and column)

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, heatmap

I have the following code:

```
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer);

setwd("~/Desktop")
mydata <- mtcars
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="euclidean")

d <- distfunc(mydata)
fit <- hclustfunc(d)
clusters <- cutree(fit, h=100)
nofclust.height <-  length(unique(as.vector(clusters)));

# Colorings
hmcols <- rev(redgreen(2750))
selcol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12,"Set3"))
selcol2 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Set1"))
clustcol.height = selcol2(nofclust.height);

heatmap.2(as.matrix(mydata), 
           trace='none', 
           dendrogram='both', 
           key=F,
           Colv=T, 
           scale='row',
           hclust=hclustfunc, distfun=distfunc, col=hmcols,
           symbreak=T,
           margins=c(7,10), keysize=0.1,
           lwid=c(5,0.5,3), lhei=c(0.05,0.5),
           lmat=rbind(c(5,0,4),c(3,1,2)),
           labRow=rownames(mydata),
           #ColSideColors=clustcol.height[clusters],  # This line doesn't work
           RowSideColors=clustcol.height[clusters])
```

Which produce the following figure:
[image]

What I want to do is to perform clustering on both row and column and show clustering bars (RowSideColors and ColSideColors) next to dendogram. How can I achieve that?

At the moment I only succeed in showing `RowSideColors` **but not** the `ColSideColors` one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to show both `RowSideColors` and `ColSideColors` you have to obtain cluster assignments for rows and columns of the matrix separately. At the moment object 'cluster' contains clusters that correspond to rows only.

```
# set the custom distance and clustering functions, per your example
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x, method="euclidean")

# perform clustering on rows and columns
cl.row <- hclustfunc(distfunc(mydata))
cl.col <- hclustfunc(distfunc(t(mydata)))

# extract cluster assignments; i.e. k=8 (rows) k=5 (columns)
gr.row <- cutree(cl.row, 8)
gr.col <- cutree(cl.col, 5)

# require(RColorBrewer)
col1 <- brewer.pal(8, "Set1")
col2 <- brewer.pal(5, "Pastel1")

# require(gplots)    
heatmap.2(as.matrix(mydata), hclustfun=hclustfunc, distfun=distfunc,   
          RowSideColors=col1[gr.row], ColSideColors=col2[gr.col])
```

You can examine the clustering *a priori* with `plot(cl.row)` and `plot(cl.col)`. Also you may play with the `RColorBrewer` library to select the most appropriate colour-coding. Possibly a sequential palette may be better to avoid over-colouring.